# Return a value in a different Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Running Rails:
Rails 4.2.5
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

I'm trying to return a value from one model (eds) within a view of another model (clients).

I believe I I'm very close to a solution. However, I'm at a road block. I'm want return the name of the school (eds) in the client view.

As of now, I'm defining this in my client controller:

```
def index
 @eds_school = Ed.name
end
```

I thought that `Ed.name` should work but it doesn't.
Then I'm calling the statement in the view:

```
 <tb><%= @eds_school %></td>
```

I think my issue is within the client controller.

Here is the db schema:

```
  create_table "eds", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "grade"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text     "school"
    t.text     "JtText"
  end
```

Eds Controller:

```
class EdsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ed, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /eds
  # GET /eds.json
  def index
    @eds = Ed.all
  end

  # GET /eds/1
  # GET /eds/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /eds/new
  def new
    @ed = Ed.new
  end

  # GET /eds/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /eds
  # POST /eds.json
  def create
    @ed = Ed.new(ed_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ed.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ed, notice: 'Ed was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ed }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @ed.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /eds/1
  # PATCH/PUT /eds/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ed.update(ed_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ed, notice: 'Ed was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ed }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @ed.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /eds/1
  # DELETE /eds/1.json
  def destroy
    @ed.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to eds_url, notice: 'Ed was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_ed
      @ed = Ed.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ed_params
      params.require(:ed).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Client Controller:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /clients
  # GET /clients.json
  def index
    @clients = Client.all.uniq.order("created_at DESC")
    @clients_count = Client.uniq.count
    @eds_school = Ed.name
  end

  # GET /clients/1
  # GET /clients/1.json
  def show
  #@notes = Note.all.uniq.order("created_at DESC")
  @notes = Note.where(client_id: @client.id) #Where a note belong to the current user
  end

  # GET /clients/new
  def new
    @client = Client.new
  end

  # GET /clients/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /clients
  # POST /clients.json
  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save
        format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /clients/1
  # PATCH/PUT /clients/1.json
  def update
    #if params[:remove_image]
    #@client.remove_image!
    @client.save
  #end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.update(client_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /clients/1
  # DELETE /clients/1.json
  def destroy
    @client.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to clients_url, notice: 'Client was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_client
      @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def client_params
      params.require(:client).permit(:firstName, :lastName,:dob, :name, :gender_id, :RefbText, :JtText, :text_rs, :msub, :text_id, :ged_id, :mj_id, :od_id, :otc_id, :cigarette_id, :alcohol_id, :grad, :remove_image, :rh_options, :insurance_id, :state_id, :ed_id, :wk_id, :grade_id, :rsource_id, :image, :race_id, :employment_id, :comments, :clientemail, :phone, :truma_id, :college_id, :enrolled, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode, rhealth_ids:[], mhealth_ids:[], cparent_ids:[], preg_ids:[], referral_ids:[], refa_ids:[], refb_ids:[])
      #params.require(:client).permit(:name, mhealth_ids:[])
    end
  end
```

Code Sample of Client Model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :ed
end
```

Code Sample of Client DB Schema:

```
  create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "ed_id"
end
```

Ed Controller:

```
class Ed < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :clients
end
```

Comment: yes, of course, `Ed.name` doesn't make any sense (name of which, of the many, Ed should it be?). You have to do similar to what you did in the eds_controller: `Ed.find(...).name`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: As Sergio Pointed out, you're calling name of Ed, the class, you don't want the name of the class, you want the name of an object of Ed. Something like ```Ed.find(<some ed id>).name``` If you want the name of all your schools just write a loop in your view that walks through your ed collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not completely clear what you're trying to achieve. Your code isnt working bcause name is an attribute and therefore a method on an instance of the class Eds. Look up the difference between class methods and instance methods. You need to find a particular instance of Eds and then call the name method on it e.g.

```
eds_school = Eds.find(1).name
```

where 1 is the database record in the eds table with an id of 1.

Because a client belongs to an Eds, you can access the eds name through a client instance. To display the eds.name for each client, you will need to loop through the clients variable. In the view

```
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
   <%= client.eds.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what if the first record in the DB isn't associated with the client record.

Comment: you need to show more info e.g. what is the relationship between Client and Eds

Comment: @margo I've added updated information to the bottom of the the original. Let me know if you need anything else.